# How do I change the sections titles at the ToC? (At Koma-script)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}

\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

The result is this (of the ToC):

[image]

How do I change it to:

```
sec: aaa
sec: bbb
```

I looking for a general code and not specific to each section...

**P.S. I need to put it at the preamble (because I'm using LyX), so it need to be something general and not specific to each section.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is redefining `\addsectiontocentry` to remove the section number from the TOC entry and add the prefix `sec:~`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\let\originaladdsectiontocentry\addsectiontocentry
\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}
  {\originaladdsectiontocentry{#1}{#2}} 
  {\originaladdsectiontocentry{}{sec:~#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}

\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If unnumbered sections should get the prefix too:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\let\originaladdsectiontocentry\addsectiontocentry
\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \originaladdsectiontocentry{}{sec:~#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{aaa}
\section{bbb}
\addsec{ccc}

\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to define the short title as sec:aaa:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section[sec: aaa]{aaa}
\section[sec: bbb]{bbb}

\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I'm using LyX so I need something general...

Comment: There is a way to do it general?

Comment: Maybe, you should define your problem then properly... Tell us exactly, what you want to have, what you are using and so on...

Comment: You right - I edit my question or it's not clear enough...

Comment: It's still not solving the problem, if you compile your code you will see that the numbers still appear... I want to remove them.

Comment: [link](https://johnrhudson.me.uk/computing/Tips_tricks_and_extended_features_of_LyX_LaTeX.pdf)
There is written, how to enter short titles in lyx.
BTW: You never told, that there should be no numbers in the ToC...

Comment: Thank you for the great link! I wrote it at my moc-up